# Question about bisection method

Tags: calculus, functions, roots

We have $f(x)=(x-1)^3(x-2)(x-3)$.
$a_0<1,b_0>3$. We had to show that if $\frac{a_0+b_0}{2}\ne 1,2,3$, there is one root of $f$ that we can't get it by the bisection method.

I guess that this is $2$, I did few tests and I never get $2$, but I didn't understand why...

Can you help me please,
Thank you!

Comment: The first step that lands inside $(1,3)$ cuts away two roots from the further computations. There is one root that gets always cut away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, we have that $f(a_0) < 0$ and $f(b_0) > 0$. Notice that at each step $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ of the bisection method, the sign of $f$ at each endpoint does not change (that is, we will always have that $f(a_k) < 0$ and $f(b_k) > 0$).

Hence, to see why the bisection method will never bracket the root $x = 2$, it suffices to observe that, provided that you look at a small enough neighbourhood around $2$ (say, with radius $\epsilon = 0.5$), the endpoints of any closed interval $[a,b]$ that brackets $x = 2$ must satisfy $f(a) > 0$ and $f(b) < 0$ (that is, $f$ changes from positive to negative at $x = 2$). But as we observed above, our initial choices of $a_0$ and $b_0$ make this impossible.

Comment: So if I'm understand you correct, the reason why we wont get $2$ is because $a_k,b_k$ swap sign?

Comment: Yes; $a_k$ and $b_k$ never switch signs during the algorithm, and any small enough closed interval that brackets $x = 2$ would require $a_k$ and $b_k$ to have their signs different from the initial choices of $a_0$ and $b_0$.

Answer (score 1):

A clear answer has been given for the "general" case by Adriano. But the result as stated is not precisely true. For instance, let $a_0=0$ and $b_0=8$. Then $a_1=0$ and $b_1=4$, and the next iteration stumbles into $2$.